# Yesterday day however to exclude Sunday

Tags: google-bigquery

I know you can use a `Case When` statement to get yesterday day which I can include a response as Yes or No (looking at a historic dates). However I need to exclude Sunday. For example, when the date hits Monday, it needs to look at Saturday as yesterday results. Is this possible?

Comment: OK thanks for the advise. I am not sure what you meant by 'You Must Not Capitalize Each And Every Single Word In The English Language'

Comment: **DO NOT** start every single word in the English sentence with a capital letter - use lowercase, too! Capital letters are only at the beginning of a sentence, or if the word is a (geographical) name, a company name, something Holy or Royal - any other words do **NOT** start with a capital letter

Comment: So Sunday and Monday have the same yesterday?

Comment: Hi Martin Weitzmann, So my company updates a table for me everyday which loads new data which is date stamped apart from Sunday. I have used Data Studio to create a Dashboard however when using the yesterday function one of my tables error out due to no data being loaded on Sunday. So I need to create a Yes or No field in Big Query to identify whether a date is yesterday or not but the calculation needs to know that Monday needs to look at Saturday data.

Comment: This is what I have so far CASE WHEN File_Date = Date_Sub(Current_Date(), INTERVAL 1 Day) Then 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS Yesterday. This works however as Sunday dosent load any data on Monday I need it to default Yesterday to Saturday Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
WITH my_day AS (
  SELECT DATE("2020-08-08") AS curr_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE("2020-08-09") AS curr_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE("2020-08-10") AS curr_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE("2020-08-11") AS curr_date)
SELECT
  curr_date,
  if (FORMAT_DATE('%A', curr_date) = "Monday", DATE_SUB(curr_date, INTERVAL 2 DAY), DATE_SUB(curr_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as prev_date,
FROM
  my_day;
```

Comment: Hi Soumendra, Thank you for that. This is what I have so far CASE WHEN File_Date = Date_Sub(Current_Date(), INTERVAL 1 Day) Then 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS Yesterday. This works however as Sunday dosent load any data on Monday I need it to default Yesterday to Saturday Data.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly doing that. Both `2020-08-09` and `2020-08-10`, it calculates, previous date as `2020-08-08`

Comment: I am looking at historic data and it goes back all the way to June 2019. Would I need to write  select date for every single date as the date range is always changing.

Comment: No, you need to read date column value from a table. `SELECT "<date-column>", IF(FORMAT_DATE('%A', "<date-column>") = "Monday", DATE_SUB("<date-column>", INTERVAL 2 DAY), DATE_SUB("<date-column>", INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as prev_date FROM "<table-name>"`

Comment: Can you explain what the above code is actually doing. I am new to coding and learning something new everyday. What does date-column refer to. It dosent refer to my date reference File_Date.

Comment: The "<date-column>" refers to your "File_Date" and the second column (starts with IF) calculates the yesterday's date.
`SELECT File_Date, IF(FORMAT_DATE('%A', Current_Date()) = "Monday", DATE_SUB(Current_Date(), INTERVAL 2 DAY), DATE_SUB(Current_Date(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as prev_date FROM "table-name";`

Comment: Thank you very much I will give it a go, any problems will let you know.

Comment: Soumendra just one more question if I wanted to select the first date of every month is that possible as the file date for the first of the month is not always 2020/01/01 it could be the second of the month or the third. I need the minimum File Date for each month.

Comment: Please try this `SELECT IF(FORMAT_DATE('%A', File_Date) = "Sunday", DATE_ADD(File_Date, INTERVAL 1 DAY), File_Date) as first_working_day`

Comment: Thank you will give it all a go.

Comment: Please consider voting up the answer if it helped !

Comment: Apologies am new to this am not sure whether it allowed me to voting up.

Comment: Hi Soumendra, Thank you very much for your help previously. In regards to the second query, it dosent provide me with the correct answer. I require the minimum date of every month recorded e.g. In January it can be 01/01/2020 but in February it can be 02/02/2020. Can you please advise.